# how to json list after converting into json

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sorting

i am trying this but getting error . whats other way to sort this list of items .

getting error  Value of tuple type

> '(String, JSON)' has no member 'subscript'

```
  let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bizSnapshot.value as Any, options: .prettyPrinted)
  var bizOfferingsJson = try JSON(data: jsonData)
```

`bizOfferingsJson` items contains itemIndex as key as Int , i want to sort based on that itemIndex

```
 bizOfferingsJson = bizOfferingsJson.sorted(by: { $0.["itemIndex"] > $1.["itemIndex"] })

  print("bizOfferingsJson===",bizOfferingsJson)
```

sample bizOfferingsJson data

```
[
  {
    "isVisible" : true,
    "itemRetailInfo" : {
      "units" : "GRAMS",
      "quantityPrice" : [
        {
          "discountPrice" : 0,
          "regularPrice" : 25,
          "quantity" : 1000,
          "quantitySelected" : 1000,
          "isEditable" : false
        }
      ]
    },
    "imageStoragePathList" : [
      "ONION_RED.png"
    ],
    "bizOfferingsID" : "Vegetables_0",
    "masterImage" : 0,
    "vegNonVegInfoEnum" : "NONE",
    "description" : "",
    "itemQunatitySelected" : 0,
    "bizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree" : {
      "indexOrder" : 0,
      "headerText" : "Vegetables",
      "isVisible" : true
    },
    "itemIndex" : 0,
    "totalCountQunatity" : 0,
    "primaryText" : "Onion Red"
  },
  {
    "isVisible" : true,
    "itemRetailInfo" : {
      "units" : "GRAMS",
      "quantityPrice" : [
        {
          "discountPrice" : 0,
          "regularPrice" : 25,
          "quantity" : 1000,
          "quantitySelected" : 1000,
          "isEditable" : false
        }
      ]
    },
    "imageStoragePathList" : [
      "POTATO.png"
    ],
    "bizOfferingsID" : "Vegetables_1",
    "masterImage" : 0,
    "vegNonVegInfoEnum" : "NONE",
    "description" : "",
    "itemQunatitySelected" : 0,
    "bizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree" : {
      "indexOrder" : 0,
      "headerText" : "Vegetables",
      "isVisible" : true
    },
    "itemIndex" : 1,
    "totalCountQunatity" : 0,
    "primaryText" : "Potato"
  },
  {
    "isVisible" : true,
    "itemRetailInfo" : {
      "units" : "PIECES",
      "quantityPrice" : [
        {
          "discountPrice" : 0,
          "regularPrice" : 3,
          "quantity" : 1,
          "quantitySelected" : 0.10000000000000001,
          "isEditable" : false
        }
      ]
    },
    "imageStoragePathList" : [
      "CORIANDER_LEAVES_BUNCH.png"
    ],
    "bizOfferingsID" : "Vegetables_2",
    "masterImage" : 0,
    "vegNonVegInfoEnum" : "NONE",
    "description" : "",
    "itemQunatitySelected" : 0,
    "bizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree" : {
      "indexOrder" : 0,
      "headerText" : "Vegetables",
      "isVisible" : true
    },
    "itemIndex" : 2,
    "totalCountQunatity" : 0,
    "primaryText" : "Coriander Leaves Bunch"
  },
  {
    "isVisible" : true,
    "itemRetailInfo" : {
      "units" : "GRAMS",
      "quantityPrice" : [
        {
          "discountPrice" : 0,
          "regularPrice" : 8,
          "quantity" : 500,
          "quantitySelected" : 500,
          "isEditable" : false
        }
      ]
    },
    "imageStoragePathList" : [
      "TOMATO_STANDARD.png"
    ],
    "bizOfferingsID" : "Vegetables_3",
    "masterImage" : 0,
    "vegNonVegInfoEnum" : "NONE",
    "description" : "",
    "itemQunatitySelected" : 0,
    "bizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree" : {
      "indexOrder" : 0,
      "headerText" : "Vegetables",
      "isVisible" : true
    },
    "itemIndex" : 3,
    "totalCountQunatity" : 0,
    "primaryText" : "Tomato Standard"
  }
]
```

Comment: Why do you convert an array to JSON and then back to an array? (in my opinion SwiftyJSON doesn't create completety different types ). And why pretty-printed? Non-humans like a computer don't care at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify which type you sort assuming an array

```
var bizOfferingsJson = try JSON(data: jsonData).array! 
bizOfferingsJson = bizOfferingsJson.sorted(by: { $0["itemIndex"] > $1["itemIndex"] })
```

or using mutating `sort`

```
bizOfferingsJson.sort{ $0["itemIndex"] > $1["itemIndex"] }
```

using `Codable` is much better given your json

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let isVisible: Bool
    let itemRetailInfo: ItemRetailInfo
    let imageStoragePathList: [String]
    let bizOfferingsID: String
    let masterImage: Int
    let vegNonVegInfoEnum, purpleDescription: String
    let itemQunatitySelected: Int
    let bizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree: BizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree
    let itemIndex, totalCountQunatity: Int
    let primaryText: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isVisible, itemRetailInfo, imageStoragePathList, bizOfferingsID, masterImage, vegNonVegInfoEnum
        case purpleDescription = "description"
        case itemQunatitySelected, bizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree, itemIndex, totalCountQunatity, primaryText
    }
}

// MARK: - BizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree
struct BizOfferingsHeaderTypeThree: Codable {
    let indexOrder: Int
    let headerText: String
    let isVisible: Bool
}

// MARK: - ItemRetailInfo
struct ItemRetailInfo: Codable {
    let units: String
    let quantityPrice: [QuantityPrice]
}

// MARK: - QuantityPrice
struct QuantityPrice: Codable {
    let discountPrice, regularPrice, quantity: Int
    let quantitySelected: Double
    let isEditable: Bool
}
```

---

```
var res = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: jsonData)
res.sort { $0.itemIndex > $1.itemIndex }
```

Comment: if i am adding .array!  then i am getting error in my next line where i am setting json to swift model class Cannot convert value of type '[JSON]' to expected argument type 'JSON?'

Comment: according to your current code model should be `[JSON]` you need to deal with it as an array